# Communicating parent content page in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a Content Page and a Content View. Content page used the view in that and in view, there is a button, whenever the button is clicked, view needs to call a content page method.

For example, CP is the content page and CV is the content view page with a button.

CP Code:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Detail Page"></Label>
            <local:CV CustomProperty="" />
        </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

CV Code:

```
<ContentView.Content>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Spacing="0">
            <Button Text="Click Me" Clicked="Button_Clicked">

            </Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView.Content>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `ContentView` in other words is a custom control and the common way of achieving such a behaviour is to use [BindableProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties) and [DataBindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics). So you need to create a `BindableProperty` of type `ICommand` and bind it to the `Button`.

Usage example:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Detail Page"></Label>
            <local:CV CustomProperty="" ButtonTapCommand="{Binding MyDesiredCommand}" />
        </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

P.S.: There are other available approaches, but if you want a proper reusable `View` thats the preferred way to go.

Comment: So ButtonTapCommand is a public property on view, right? What is MyDesiredCommand, is it a method of content page?

Comment: Yes, you have to create a public property with name ButtonTapCommand of type ICommand in your view.

Comment: I defined that but not sure about use of MyDesiredCommand, can you let me know, how can i use it? I am new to Xamarin.

Comment: MyDesiredCommand is an instance of Command that should be in your ViewModel and should be bound to ButtonTapCommand. Check the official docs if you need more input on Commands: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/commanding